# using nsight to debug

Tags: c++, c, cuda, nsight

I am using NSight to debug my CUDA code and I have question:
how can I place a breakpoint for a specific thread and block?

When I place a breakpoint on the kernel the debugger always stops at thread 0 of block 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use CUDA Debug Focus. you can debug any thread in any block you want...

Answer (score 9):

As discussed in the online help in Nsight, you can set a breakpoint and make it conditional on block and thread id like this:

To set a block or thread condition on a CUDA C breakpoint:

1. Set a breakpoint on a line of source code.
2. Right-click on the breakpoint.
3. From the drop-down menu, select Condition...
4. Type:

   @blockIdx(0,2,0) && @threadIdx(5,0,0)
5. Click OK. The breakpoint glyph shows a plus sign.